# How to toggle class by a button click?

Tags: javascript

How to toggle class by a button click?

How to remove a class on the next click from the same button?

```html
  <button onclick="goldborder()" id="btn">Click here</button>
```

JS:

```js
function goldborder() {
  let boxs = document.getElementById('box');
  boxs.classList.add('bordercolor');
}
```

Comment: You can check the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.
If the class exists it removes and if not it adds in it.

```
boxs.classList.toggle('bordercolor');
```